# How to replace certain pattern in a file while keeping some string (could be any string) within it unchanged?

Tags: regex, sed, vim

We know that in Linux vim, we can use

```
:%s/character/symbol/g
```

to replace any occurrence of 'character' with 'symbol' in a file.

But what if I want to replace patterns like:

```
defined($opt_ws_parser)
defined($opt_client)
defined($opt_server)
 ...
```

with only the part in the parentheses? That is:

```
$opt_ws_parser
$opt_client
$opt_server
...
```

How can I achieve that?
I tried using "%s/defined($.*)/$.*/g". It turned out that all the occurrences became $.*, its literal form, not retaining their original letters.

Comment: Please refer to the [`test` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Comment: The important thing to remember is that makefile recipes are not written in "makefile syntax".  They are shell scripts.  So if you want to understand the syntax of a makefile recipe you need to read the shell documentation not the make documentation.

Comment: The title of the proposed duplicate is disingenuous, but the answers explain exactly how to RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/defined(\(\$.*\))/\1
```

- `%` - Repeat for every line
- `s` - Substitute
- `/` - Start of pattern
- `defined(` - Match the string "defined(" literally
- `\(` - Beginning of capture group
- `\$` - Match "$"
- `.*` - Match anything
- `\)` - End of capture group
- `)` - Literally match ")"
- `/` - End of pattern, start of substitution string
- `\1` - Reference to the first capture group (first expression between round brackets)

Sources:

- [:h :substitute](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute)
- [:h :sub-replace-special](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)